# Escaping & in GET

Tags: php, get

I have this link:

```
http://localhost/dow.php?url=/site.net/page.php?action=download&id=3424&authkey=234234324242342
```

and

```
$_GET["url"]
```

should be

```
=/site.net/page.php?action=download&id=3424&authkey=234234324242342`
```

but when i try

```
print $_GET["url"];
```

it only prints `/site.net/page.php?action=download`

The problem it's obviously with & char, i tried `htmlspecialchars($_GET["url"])` with no luck.
What can i do to have the entire string?

Comment: Encode them before you print your link, then decode it after you click it

Answer (score 0):

Nope that is because the other two params are different.

You need to get each of them separately. like `$_GET['id'], $_GET['authkey']`

or you could just make use of a `foreach` construct.

```
foreach($_GET as $k=>$v)
{
 $myparams[$k]=$v;
}

echo $myparams['authkey'];// "prints" 234234324242342
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where did you get the target url, but try encode it before you print it in the get.
i.e `encodeURIComponent` function in JS, `rawurlencode` in PHP, or just use this [ref here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) to replace any html chars you want. And `rawurldecode` it after `$_GET['url']`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the full request you'll have to use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`

eg :

```
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```